# Combining a list of dataframes into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a dataframe that combines historical price data for various ETFs (XLF, XLP, XLU, etc) downloaded from yahoo finance. I tried to create a dataframe for each ETF, with the date and the adjusted close. Now I want to combine them all into one dataframe. Any idea why this doesn't work?

I've tried saving each csv as a dataframe, which only has date and adjusted close. Then I want to combine, using Date as the index.

```
# Here's what I've tried.

import os
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

XLF_df = pd.read_csv("datasets/XLF.csv").set_index("Date")["Adj Close"]
XRT_df = pd.read_csv("datasets/XRT.csv").set_index("Date")["Adj Close"]
XLP_df = pd.read_csv("datasets/XLP.csv").set_index("Date")["Adj Close"]
XLY_df = pd.read_csv("datasets/XLY.csv").set_index("Date")["Adj Close"]
XLV_df = pd.read_csv("datasets/XLV.csv").set_index("Date")["Adj Close"]

dfList = [XLF_df, XRT_df, XLP_df, XLY_df, XLV_df]

df = reduce(lambda df1,df2: pd.merge(df1,df2,on="Date"), dfList)

df.head()
```

I get an empty dataframe! And if I say on="id" then I get a key error.

Comment: Try `pd.concat(dfList )`

Comment: should work, have you checked XLF_df, XRT_df, XLP_df, XLY_df and XLV_df ?

Comment: I checked XLF_df.head(), and it gave me values in the adjusted close column. Wonder where its value is going when it merges?

Comment: @dimitris_ps pd.concat worked, but what is the name of the resulting dataframe, is it df? When I enter df.head() I still get empty data.